# Renaming second production web app and set it to PROD SP On prem

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, dns

I am working with SP On prem 2019. On production farm, we have a web app and root site collection is created in it. DNS was also setup for this web app and so the root site is accessible with url: sharepoint.domainname.com/. --Current PROD Site

On the same server, we have another web app with root site collection created and DNS is added as well, so the URL is: sp.domainname.com/ --New Testing Prod Site.

Now we migrated all data from sharepoint to sp and we are looking to perform a switch so was wondering the best way to achieve this.

For End users, we want to keep URL same but pointing to different site instead of current one. They access sharepoint currently by typing in sharepoint.domainname.com which we would want them to continue doing so.

So i would like to rename sharepoint.domainname.com to a different url and then change sp.domainname.com to sharepoint.domainname.com. I am not sure the best way to achieve this.

Can someone shed light if done in the past, thanks in advance.